# Print all the matching pattern in Vim without context - Vim equivalent for `grep -o`

Tags: vim

How is it possible to print all match values in Vim?

I search a Vim equivalent for `grep -o <pattern> | sort | uniq`.

The solution shall work independently from the OS and and without using grep.

## Example

Given that you have the search pattern `/\w\+um\>/` and the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum pulvinar
aliquam viverra. Aenean accumsan et neque ac hendrerit.

Suspendisse tincidunt congue bibendum. Duis egestas tempor feugiat. 
Curabitur egestas nunc nisi, id tristique libero finibus et. 

Pellentesque lacus ex, molestie eget neque eget, ullamcorper gravida quam. 
In rutrum et lectus luctus faucibus. In sollicitudin rutrum accumsan. Sed 
quis libero viverra, dignissim metus vehicula, viverra urna. Proin sed diam 
pellentesque, dictum tortor eget, sollicitudin eros.
```

Is there any way to print every words ending with `um`?

```
ipsum
Vestibulum
bibendum
rutrum
rutrum
dictum
```

Even better: is there any way to print every unique word ending with `um`?

```
bibendum
dictum
ipsum
rutrum
Vestibulum
```

My first trials was to used the command `:g//`. However all the line search is printed, which does *not* correspond to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ex commands tend to be line-oriented and there is no built-in function that does exactly what you want.

This would work for the first requirement:

```
:echo getline(1,'$')
    \ ->join()
    \ ->split(' ')
    \ ->filter({ _, v -> v =~ '\w\+um\>' })
    \ ->join("\n")
```

Where you:

- get a list of all the lines with `:help getline()`,
- turn the list of lines into a single string with `:help join()`,
- split the single string into a list of words with `:help split()`,
- filter the list according to your pattern with `:help filter()`,
- turn the list into a single multiline string with `join()`,
- echo it.

You may want to add an extra step to remove punctuation.

Add `:help uniq()` for the second requirement:

```
:echo getline(1,'$')
    \ ->join()
    \ ->split(' ')
    \ ->filter({ _, v -> v =~ '\w\+um\>' })
    \ ->uniq()
    \ ->join("\n")
```